# How to get link tag to take all of the space in a table cell?

Tags: html, css

```css
p{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

.table {
  display:table;
}

.headers, .row {
  display:table-row;
}

.value, .header {
  display:table-cell;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.value a, .header {
  padding:10px;
}

.value a {
  background-color:#9a9;
  display:block;
}

.spacer {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
My Fruit Stores
</h1>
<div class="table">
    <div class="headers">
        <div class="header">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Money</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Employees</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">Store 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">$1,800</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">16</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value spacer">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">Store 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">$800</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value spacer">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have yet to get this link tag to take up all of the space of the table cell.

The idea here is that the entire row would be a link to the same place. I need the table to take up the width of its container so that is why I have this '.spacer' div.

So in my example you would click anywhere on the table row in order to get to a page about the store that the row represents.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** To be more clear, the problem is most specifically about the purposefully empty .spacer item that is being used to fill the remainder of the space to the right of the table row. If you look at this last table cell item you can see that it's height is not the same height as the rest of the table cells. I would like for the last '.spacer' item to fill up all of the space so it looks like a proper table.

Comment: So if someone clicks $1,800 or 16 they should go to the same place right? (because they are in the same row)

Comment: @Pat Yea, now looking back this is unrelated to what I actually need help with. They should be able to click on any of the white-space in the row to use the row's link. That is why I have the link elements taking up all of the space. The problem is that the last item that I am using in the row is empty because I need it to fill the rest of the area to the right. But as you can see in the example, the last item is not taking up all of the space that it should, you can see that it's height is not the same height as the other table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a whitespace `&nbsp;` within the empty anchor tag and set the `text-decoration: none` for `.space a` css selector

```css
p{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

.table {
  display:table;
}

.headers, .row {
  display:table-row;
}

.value, .header {
  display:table-cell;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.value a, .header {
  padding:10px;
}

.value a {
  background-color:#9a9;
  display:block;
}

.spacer {
  width:100%;
}

.spacer a{  
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
My Fruit Stores
</h1>
<div class="table">
    <div class="headers">
        <div class="header">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Money</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Employees</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">Store 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">$1,800</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">16</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value spacer">
            <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">Store 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">$800</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value spacer">
            <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could set the `a` within `spacer` to `position:absolute` and set its `height` & `width` to 100% as below

```css
p{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

.table {
  display:table;
}

.headers, .row {
  display:table-row;
}

.value, .header {
  display:table-cell;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.value a, .header {
  padding:10px;
}

.value a {
  background-color:#9a9;
  display:block;
}

.spacer {
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer a{  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>
My Fruit Stores
</h1>
<div class="table">
    <div class="headers">
        <div class="header">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Money</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Employees</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">Store 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">$1,800</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">16</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value spacer">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">Store 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">$800</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="#">6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="value spacer">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```